# How can I convert my old MySQL raw data files

Tags: upgrade, mysql, webserver

After an upgrade of my webserver from 12.04.5 LTS‬ to 16.04.2 LTS, my webserver no longer worked and I was forced to reinstall the server.

Unfortunately, I was only able to backup the raw database files from /var/lib/mysql without being able to make .sql backups.

I have reinstalled the server with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and copied the backed up database files into the respective locations, but they do not work. The permissions were set to mysql:mysql - so that is not the problem. On the old system, I had MySQL version 5.5.53 and the new version is now 5.7.19. The system is running with Plesk Onyx 17.5.3 Update #17.

How can I correctly convert my raw MySQL files (*.frm, *.myd, *.myi) to work properly on the upgraded server?

I suspect I have to be able to first convert the old files to .sql format and then import them again on the new server?

But how?

I am a beginner with Linux, but do know enough to run command line commands. I often use Midnight Commander for configuration, etc. as well as Plesk.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu... "That does not work" is rather meaningless. What is the exact error message you're getting as the files should be compatible within major MySQL versions...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to first check your databases with a compatible environment. E.g. a docker container

```
docker run --name mysql55 --detach --env=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql/mysql-server:5.5.53
```

will get you such an environment
https://severalnines.com/blog/mysql-docker-containers-understanding-basics
shows you how to go from there.

Now you can check with other versions whether the import works. Personally I would not go for 5.7.19 directly since that version has "features" that make handling it more difficult then e.g. 5.7.14. E.g. in my environment a 5.7.14 docker image works on Mac an Linux but a 5.7.19 does not. See http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Docker_on_Mac